# How do I display JavaScript, PHP, and other source code of web development languages in regular HTML pages without using a web application?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I want to be able to write javascript, php, and other source codes in my HTML page but not have it run. aka, it would just be on the page fully readable rather than being turned into code and displayed as such.

For example I'd want `<php echo "Hello World!"; ?>`
to show up, rather than it to be run as a hello world program.

Comment: Dared to inspect the source of _this_ website? : ))

Comment: I did, but it's a web application ]: I think.

Comment: I think it's a bit off topic, but shouldn't it be  < **?** php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>

Comment: It's `HTML` + `CSS`, definitely not a web application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
echo htmlentities('<?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>');
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I neeeded.

Answer (score 1):

```
<pre><code>code here</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perform the following text replacements, or at least the first two. (The PHP [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function performs the first four to allow for use of escaped text, when double quoted, as attribute values.) See the "[Named character references](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Introduction#Named_character_references)" section of the *MDN Introduction to HTML*.

- `&` with `&amp;`
- `<` with `&lt;`
- `>` with `&gt;`
- `"` with `&quot;`
- `'` with `&#39;` or `&#039;` (or `&apos;` in documents that don't have to validate as HTML 4)

Then surround the code in [`<pre>...</pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/pre).

---

Some example code:

```
<script>
var url = location.href;
if (url.indexOf('hello') >= 0 && url.indexOf('world') >= 0) {
    alert('hello, world');
}
</script>
```

becomes

```
<pre>
&lt;script type="text/javascript">
var url = location.href;
if (url.indexOf('hello') >= 0 &amp;&amp; url.indexOf('world') >= 0) {
    alert('hello, world');
}
&lt;/script>
</pre>
```

or

```
<pre>
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
var url = location.href;
if (url.indexOf(&#39;hello&#39;) &gt;= 0 &amp;&amp; url.indexOf(&#39;world&#39;) &gt;= 0) {
    alert(&#39;hello, world&#39;);
}
&lt;/script&gt;
</pre>
```